# Вызов диалогового окна из фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

У меня есть 2 активности и в одной из них Bottom navigation activity и 3 фрагмента ее кнопок. В одной из фрагментов кнопка, при ее нажатии должно вылезти диалоговое окно. Как реализовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать например так:

```
val dialog = Dialog(context!!)
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogueLayout)


dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.someBtn).setOnClickListener {}

Objects.requireNonNull<Window>(dialog.window).setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
dialog.show()
```

Код выше - обычное диалоговое окно. Так же, с учетом того что вы использовали метку `dialogFragment`, то диалог можно показать и сделать таким образом. Создаем диалоговый класс:

```
class DialogFrg: DialogFragment() {
    val TAG: String = DialogFrg::class.java.simpleName

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val bundle = arguments
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogFrg, container, false)

        return view
    }

}
```

и дальше из фрагмента делаем вызов:

```
val dialogFrg= DialogFrg()
val bundle = Bundle()
dialogFrg.arguments = bundle


val ft = Objects.requireNonNull<FragmentManager>(fragmentManager).beginTransaction()
dialogFrg.show(ft, dialogFrg.TAG)
```

Это два варианта как показать диалог в фрагменте. Вот есть еще [туториал](https://metanit.com/java/android/18.2.php) и [статья](https://metanit.com/java/android/18.2.php). Если вам нужно сделать полноэкранный диалог на базе DialogFragment, то нужно сделать стиль:

```
<style name="FullScreenDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dialog_back</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/down_from_top</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/up_from_bottom</item>
    </style>
```

и его подключить в методе `onCreate`:

```
setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle)
```